# Closest power to a factorial

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For a given natural number $n$, I would like to find two integers $m<n$ and $k$ such that $m^k$ is as a close as possible to $n!$. I am not sure how to begin tackling this question.

Comment: Are you trying to do this mathematically (i.e. hoping for a closed form) or computationally?

Comment: Computationally, i.e., an algorithm that will find the answer efficiently, will also work for my purposes. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. (For future reference, that's the kind of thing to put in the question). Also, do you need the closest one, or will one that's "sufficiently close" (for some other definition of sufficient) work?

Comment: Duly noted (apologies; I'm new here). "Sufficiently close" will also work. I think in my case ~poly(n) will be considered reasonably close although I must admit I'm not sure that that's the best definition of closeness I am after.

Comment: No problem. We were all new here once. What do you mean by "~poly(n)"? Do you mean that the difference between $n!$ and $m^k$ is like a polynomial, or that their quotient is, or something else?

Comment: I suggest first solving the problem for fixed $k$, using a Stirling-like approximation to find the closest $m$. Then, in the outer loop of the algorithm, take the best solution where $k$ ranges from $2$ to $\log_2 n!$.

Comment: I mean that their difference is not of the order of $n!$ or $2^n$ but perhaps $n^a$ for some constant $a$ for example. Thanks for helping me elucidate the question.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I was hoping to find an algorithm with complexity that is poly-logarithmic in $n$ (rather than logarithmic in $n!$) but of course I may be asking for too much.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect you can get within $n^{1/2+\epsilon}$ by fixing $k=2$ and working in floating-point arithmetic, which is constant-time in $n$ so long as $n<2^{24}$ or so.

Comment: @ChrisCulter I believe that gives a ratio of $n^{1/2+\epsilon}$, or a difference basically on the order of $n!$.